# How to echo category names into an array wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the category names into the following array

```
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    $this->settings['categoriesmain1'] = array(
        'section' => 'general',
        'title'   => __( 'Example Select' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'This is a description for the drop-down.' ),
        'type'    => 'select',
        'std'     => '',
        'choices' => array(
            $categories => $categories // here i am trying to echo them
        )
    );
```

`choices` by default they are smth like this

```
'choices' => array(
      'Choice 1' => 'Other Choice 1',
      'Choice 2' => 'Other Choice 2',
      'Choice 3' => 'Other Choice 3'
)
```

But when i try to echo them with `$categories => $categories` I get error `Illegal offset type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 0,
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    $categories_name = array();
    foreach($categories as $category){
        $categories_name[] = $category->name;
    }
    $this->settings['categoriesmain1'] = array(
        'section' => 'general',
        'title'   => __( 'Example Select' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'This is a description for the drop-down.' ),
        'type'    => 'select',
        'std'     => '',
        'choices' =>  $categories_name
        )
    );
$settings = get_option('mytheme_options');
$my_choices  = $settings['categoriesmain1'];
var_dump($my_choices);
```

Comment: It echo's `string(8) "choice 1" string(8) "choice 1"`

Comment: what it should echo instead ?

Comment: the category names should be echoed

Comment: oh sorry i didnt notice one thing. look here what $categories return http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: it returns an array of `category objects` not `category names` so first make an array containing only categories name and then pass it to `choices`

Comment: I am trying to focus :). Smth like `$array = array($category->cat_name)` and after i add it to `$my_choices = $array`. Sorry i am limited currently :)

Comment: When you have time and if you know the answer on how to add to the array the categories please leave here a message.

Comment: Oh one more thing it echows only one category, actually the first one, i tried smth like `'choices' => array($category_name)` but only outputs array

Comment: $category_name is already an array so you dont need to add array before it

Comment: I see.. hmm, another category had been created after i implemented the code, would that be a problem? though is in a foreach loop..

Comment: `var_dump($my_choices);` shows in the header left `string(1) "0" string(1) "0"` and in the select field it's showing same a single category.

Comment: it would be difficult for me to guess whats going wrong. why dont you try ?

Comment: Got it, it is showing only the categories that have posts. Really don't know how to thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt that be:

```
'choices' => $categories
```

?

If not, you're definitely missing a step somewhere: associate each category to a key or label or whatever is needed. (The key cannot be an array: is where your error is coming from. And *each* category needs a key: not the array itself.)

Comment: I added my functions.txt could you please have a look, that is exactly what i am trying to do, just that tried your suggestion Please refresh on my txt, i updated. Now it's not sending any error. but i get some how like it blocked the page. Sorry i am quite at the beginning in wordpress.