# If condition for checkboxes in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following functions file http://pastebin.ca/2475191

I am trying to put an if condition to see if a checkbox is checked. The field that the checkbox can be found is this one

```
$this->settings['slider'] = array(
    'section' => 'general',
    'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable Slider' ),
    'desc'    => __( 'Please check the checkbox ' ),
    'type'    => 'checkbox',
    'std'     => 1 // Set to 1 to be checked 
);
```

In my back-end from what i can see the `value="1"` doesn't change, it just gets added `checkbox="checked"` when i check it.

First I have tried to see if the value is getting echoed in index.php

```
<?php 
 $settings = get_option('mytheme_options');
 $slider = $settings['slider']; // for echoing the value
 var_dump($slider);
 echo $slider;
?>
```

And when the checkbox is checked in the back-end I get echoed `string(1) "1" 1`, when it's not checked I get `Notice: Undefined index: slider` and right after in a new row `NULL`

When i try to add the condition like this

```
<?php 
  $settings = get_option('mytheme_options');
  $slider = $settings['slider'];
  if ($slider = 1) { ?>
    <div.....HTML
  <?php } else {echo "slider disabled";} ?>
```

When checkbox is not checked, I get `Notice: Undefined index: slider` and slider remains visible `AND` when the checkbox is checked i get no error and slider remains visible.

Please help me, i am quite a noob in wordpress, trying to learn and fix errors as much as i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset( $settings['slider'])) { ?>
    <div.....HTML
  <?php } else {echo "slider disabled";} ?>
```

to check between two values use

**== (comparison operator) or ===(identity operator) = is assignment operator**

which means to assign value .

```
$slider = 1 // it will assign 1 as an integer value to $slider

/*****************************/

$slider =1;
$slider == 1 // check if $slider value is one both 1 (integer) and "1" a string will return true

/*****************************/


$slider =1;
$slider === "1" //  check if $slider value is 1 and its type is string.  here it will return false as value is of $slider is one but type is int not string
```

Comment: Almost working ok. Just that when the checkbox is unchecked, Slider disappears - good, there is an echo `slider disabled` - good, just that error doesn't disappear Notice: Undefined index: slider. When it's checked everything is ok. Please help me, error is driving me crazy. Also i appreciate for helping me before.

Comment: YES, Thanks again pr1nc3. Thank you so much. Would not have done it without you, same for all past problem, btw, when do i find you online at stackoverflow?

Comment: oh i forgot to add indian time. but stackoverflow is always crowded with genius ppl

Comment: Ok, cool btw if you have time could you also please have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881712/how-to-echo-category-names-into-an-array-wordpress it has the same functions.txt

Comment: check out my ans on that